# matplotlib fig showing empty, but when prompted again it shows

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a plot function, plot(), that formats my plot and returns it.

```
ReturnValues = plot()
plt.show (block=False)
fig1
```

where fig1 displays an empty plot, but with the corrected axes but w/o the data
But when I enter 'fig1' in a new cell, it displays the plot with the data and axes and all is well.
For WHY?

In the plot() function I have this:

```
fig1 = plt.Figure()     
ax=fig1.add_subplot(111)     
ax.plot(x_axis,y_axis)     
ax.set_ylabel(plot_y)     
ax.set_xlabel(plot_x)
```

where fig1 and ax are global variables, and at the end I return

```
RV = a,b,c,d...fig1,ax
```

I expected to see the plot with data. But everything abt the plot shows EXCEPT the data

#### Blank Plot

[image: Blank Plot]

#### Plot after I run fig1 in new cell

[image: Plot after I run fig1 in new cell]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to format your code such that it is properly readable

Comment: @JRiggles i made edit saying i don't know how to . Every time I do new line in code block it just adds 3 spaces instead of new line

Comment: The easiest way to format a block of code here is to add three backticks \``` or tildes ~~~ on a line, insert your code indented as normal, then close the block with another three backticks/tildes on the last line (after your code, not on the same line). [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: @JRiggles ok I edit it to be readable now

Comment: Is this in a jupyter notebook?

Comment: @jared yes it is. is that bad? jupyter lab actually.

Comment: @eoshatz42 No, I'm just clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to try

- Move `plt.show()` after `fig1`
- Alternatively, remove `plt.show()` and try just `fig1` or `display(fig1)`